# Android animation moves layout from right to left

Tags: android, animation, layout, right-to-left

I use a animation to move a layout from right to left.

The animation doesn't work correctly. When the view is moving, the bottom and right edges of moving view are painted on screen as the follow picture show.
Does anyone know the reason and how to fix this problem? thanks!

Comment: share your code otherwise its difficult to say something about ur problem without going through the code.

Comment: Where is the picture as you said? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

refer that link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141039/view-animation-right-to-left-android). That animation work on list view adapter and activity. u just try it.

private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

```
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromRight.setDuration(500);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
    }
```