# View animation right to left android

Tags: android, animation, layout-animation

I am not able to put view animation for inflated layouts.
I used the following code snippet

```
pageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.right_to_left_anim.xml));
```

and  xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
     <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="700"/>

</set>
```

Is any thing i missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you try to run the animation?

Comment: It just sliding to left to right then right to left when animating one view.

Comment: and you want what to happen instead?

Comment: I want only right to left animation.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here is the code  for the sliding animation for view.

```
1)inFromRightAnimation

    private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

        Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        inFromRight.setDuration(500);
        inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        return inFromRight;
        }

 2)outToLeftAnimation   
    private Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
    outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoLeft;
    }

3)inFromLeftAnimation

    private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
    Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromLeft.setDuration(500);
    inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromLeft;
    }

4)outToRightAnimation

    private Animation outToRightAnimation() {
    Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    outtoRight.setDuration(500);
    outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoRight;
    }
```

and now start Animation on view

```
pageView.startAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
```

Thanks,

Comment: but how to start the animation for a view.

Comment: yourview.startAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());

Comment: If it helps anyone, to avoid the animated element from snapping to its original position add e.g. outtoLeft.setFillAfter(true);

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to animate the view when it's first created, then you either need to set the `layoutAnimation` XML property or call `setLayoutAnimation()`.

If you just want to make your view look like it's moving, you need a `TranslateAnimation`; see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4214490/832776
Also if you'd like to repeat the animation, then call `setAnimationListener()` and in `onAnimationEnd()` just start the animation again.

If you're trying to move the view permanently, see this: http://www.clingmarks.com/how-to-permanently-move-view-with-animation-effect-in-android/400

Answer (score 1):

I know that you have already accepted the answer. But I think this reply will be helpful for somebody reading this. You can try **removing .xml** from, `pageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.right_to_left_anim.xml));`