# How can I change the color of my edit text which is entered by user?

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, android-edittext

I have created a signup page and I select the hint color blue now I want to change the color of text which is entered in the edit text please tell me how I can change the color of text

Here is the code of my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Signup"
android:background="@color/purple_500">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="660dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linear_round"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Please Signup..."
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="29sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView">
</TextView>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:hint="Enter your name"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
    android:id="@+id/name"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter your password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter your valid e-mail"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pass" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Enter your cell number"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="445dp"
    android:layout_height="163dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/submit" />

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/trial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/submit"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/trial" />

<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/signup_animation"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/signup" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And how can I add the marquee effect on my text view? Can I make text view scrolling from right to left?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TextView` fill whole width you need to add these lines of code

```
<TextView
    .
    .
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
```

also do not forget to set selected for `TexrtView` as below

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```

and if `TextView` does not fill width the only thing is to call this method and pass `TextView` to it.

**Kotlin**

```
    fun addMarquee(textView: TextView) {
    textView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val pixels = textView.measuredWidth - 1
            val params = textView.layoutParams
            params.width = pixels
            textView.layoutParams = params
            textView.isSelected = true
            textView.ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE
            textView.isSingleLine = true
            textView.marqueeRepeatLimit = -1
            textView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
}
```

**Java**

```
public void addMarquee(TextView textView) {
    textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int pixels = textView.getMeasuredWidth() - 1;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = pixels;
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
            textView.setSelected(true);
            textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            textView.setSingleLine(true);
            textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
            textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE:** this method only work when textView width is `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thanks but this is kotlin code and i am using java

Comment: I'm going to edit answer and add java code in next a few minutes.

Comment: It's updated.
Only need to add `addMarquee(findViewById(R.id.text));` to your `onCreate` of activity of fragment
If it's works accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`textColor` attribute changes color of text which user entered in.

```
android:textColor="@color/black"
```

`HorizontalScrollView` has one chid view, and it can be scrolled horizontally.

There's many ways to move view.

Search with keyword like
`move view animation android` or `move view programmatically android`

Comment: I dont want to add scroll view i just want to add marquee effect is there any attribute for this???

Comment: I think I misunderstood about srolling. Animation is not as easy as in css or html.

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141039/view-animation-right-to-left-android

Comment: I want to scroll my text automatically from right to left. You r right its much easier in html or css